# How to get width of an element from an ng-click without Jquery in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I would like to get dynamically the width of the **div.progress-bar** from the `ng-click`. 
My function `move($event)` on the element `div.progress-bar` returns the event with the element `div.progress-bar`. But when I click on `div.time` which is inside `div.progress-bar`, it returns the event with the element `div.time`.

I just want the **width** of the progress-bar even I click on his children.

HTML :

```
    <div class="progress-bar" ng-click="move($event)">
        <div class="time" ng-style="{'width': (current_track.time_current / current_track.time_total * 100) + '%'}"></div>
    </div>
```

CONTROLLER :

```
$scope.move = function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(e.srcElement.offsetWidth);
    var widthOfProgressBar = e.srcElement.offsetWidth;
    /* ... */
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check if the clicked element is `.progress-bar`, and if it is not, fetch the parent element:

```
var bar = e.srcElement.className === 'time'
    ? e.srcElement.parentNode
    : e.srcElement;

var widthOfProgressBar = bar.offsetWidth;
/* ... */
```

Or alternative more *Angular/jqLite* way:

```
var element = angular.element(e.srcElement),
    bar = (element.hasClass('time') ? element.parent() : element)[0];

var widthOfProgressBar = bar.offsetWidth;
/* ... */
```

Comment: Great answer @VisioN ! I take the first solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.move =  function(e){
    var width = angular.element(e.srcElement)[0].offsetWidth;

    console.log(e.offsetX ,"/", width);
}
```